How can I hash a string into a number in bash?
I am attempting to create a tunnel into a private network. I want to create a random but consistent localhost port based on the internal domain name I am trying to tunnel into between 9000-9999.
That way I can have multiple tunnels open all on different ports but its the same port per domain name each time.
Here is a little bash that I'm struggling with:
FQDN=example.internal.net
PORT=$(bash -c "RANDOM=$FQDN; echo \$(( 9000 + \$RANDOM % 1000 ))")
kubectl port-forward --namespace default service/example $PORT:433

The problem I'm having is that $RANDOM appears to require the seed to be a number rather than a string. Therefore regardless of the value of $FQDN the port is always the same.
Therefore what I'd like to do is to convert the string into a number using some kind of a consistent hashing algorithm.
FQDN=example.internal.net
SEED=$( ??? )
PORT=$(bash -c "RANDOM=$SEED; echo \$(( 9000 + \$RANDOM % 1000 ))")
kubectl port-forward --namespace default service/example $PORT:433

Does anyone know a good way to do FQDN -> SEED in the above example?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844492/bash-how-to-hash-value-of-a-string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602378/how-to-calculate-a-hash-for-a-string-url-in-bash-for-wget-caching what resaerch did you do? Check your script with shellcheck. Do not name your variables uppercase - a variable naemd $RANDOM is used by bash for random number generation. No need to run a shell inside a shell - var=$(bash -c "sript") is just var=$(script).

you can use md5 to hash the seed:
FQDN="example.internal.net"
HASH=$(echo -n "$FQDN" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')
SEED=$((0x${HASH:0:8}))
PORT=$(( 9000 + SEED % 1000 ))
echo "Generated port: $PORT"


Note that this only takes the first 8 letters of the string

Genius. No need for random either I see.

You can use cksum like so:
for fqdn in example.com example.org example.net; do
  seed=$(cksum <<<$fqdn) seed=${seed%% *}
  RANDOM=$seed
  port=$((9000 + RANDOM%1000))
  echo "$fqdn, $port"
done

This loop always prints:
example.com, 9607
example.org, 9215
example.net, 9821


TIL the chsum utility is in POSIX

@tripleee cksum

Yeah, sorry, mobile keyboard /-:
